# Return Dynamic List From Generic Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dynamic, repository-pattern

I have a method in my Generic Repository class like below:

```
public List<T> GetPagedData(int startindex, int pagesize, string sorting, Func<T, T> selector = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> pageddata = dbset;
    pageddata = pageddata.OrderBy(sorting).Skip(startindex).Take(pagesize);

    if (selector != null)
        pageddata = pageddata.Select(selector).AsQueryable();

    return pageddata.ToList();
}
```

I want to be able to return dynamic/anonymous type list from this method. I tried `Func<T, dynamic>` and `Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>` and casting here and there but I am always running into exceptions even though it compiles. Note that I intend to use it as convention based and all the column names will match.

I know this might seem a bit out there but any help is appreciated. If I am wrong also please let me know where.

Comment: If I understand correct you want to use this one method to get all kinds of list that you are looking for?? A generic output which can be easily cast into the desired type

Comment: can you show some specific errors? and how are you using this method.

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan I may or may not. Casting is not a factor. In fact type is not a factor me here that is why I mentioned `dynamic` here

Answer (score 0):

Use `var`

```
  public List<T> GetPagedData(int startindex, int pagesize, string sorting, Func<T, T>       
  selector = null)
 {
    var pageddata = dbset.OrderBy(sorting).Skip(startindex).Take(pagesize);

    if (selector != null)
       pageddata = pageddata.Select(selector).AsQueryable();

    return pageddata.ToList();
  }
```

Comment: How is `var` helping me with my problem? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 Generics

```
public List<Q> GetPagedData<T, Q>(int startindex, int pagesize, string sorting, Func<T, Q> selector = null)
{
    dynamic pageddata = dbset;
    pageddata = pageddata.OrderBy(sorting).Skip(startindex).Take(pagesize);

    return pageddata.Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

Without selector this is afaik not possible. The minimum selector is casting the input parameter of T to Q. (except T and Q are the same type or Q extends T, then the identity function is the minimum selector)

Comment: Thanks for replying but this is not going to work either because I think since `dynamic pageddata = dbset;` when I'll `pageddata.OrderBy()` it won't get the method since it is not `IQueryable` and that is what happens actually.

Comment: What is the type of dbset? Where does it come from? Can you cast it to Queryable, e.g. by ".AsQueryable()"?